# onEndReached trigger is not being called in FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Expected Behaviour: On end of page arrival the handleLoadMore function should be get called. But it's not getting called. [Using Functional Component].

I have tried in below way. But didn't find any solution.

Using [FlatGrid](https://github.com/saleel/react-native-super-grid) component (Library based on FlatList).
Directly used FlatList also. The problem still remains.

```
      <FlatGrid
        itemDimension={130}
        items={offers}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
        initialNumToRender={2}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
        windowSize={2}
        onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
      />
```

HandleLoadMore function -

```
  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);

    console.log('PageNumber', pageNumber);
    console.log('Item Length', offers.length);
    offersAction.getOffers(pageNumber);
  };
```

Console Output -

[image]

Comment: Can you post entire code of the component? Maybe there is something wrong with setPageNumber or so

Comment: what happens when you use the full example? https://github.com/saleel/react-native-super-grid#flatgrid-example

Comment: I entirely replaced code with a sample console.log('Hello'). It's still not working. The problem is 'handleLoadMore' function is not getting called after reaching end of list. @WojciechDynus

Comment: Worked perfectly with all data loads. I guess the problem is not in 'FlatGrid'. Replaced FlatGrid with FlaitList... Still getting same behaviour. @TreyCopeland

Comment: From your output it looks like it's working fine, what's the issue?

Comment: When i scroll to the end of the list the 'handleLoadMore' function is not getting called twice. @zaytrix

Comment: Try setting `onEndReachedThreshold` to 1

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 1):

I used ScrollView as wrapper for FlatList in Parent Component. Which was creating the issue as mentioned in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14756.

Instead of 'ScrollView' using 'View' wrapper solved the issue.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to bind `handleLoadMore` to the class. From [The React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

> Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as
>   `onClick={this.handleClick}`, you should bind that method.

Comment: I am using Functional Component. It's for Class based component. Thanks for notifying. Adding this info in question.

Comment: Then you can invoke the method immediately e.g. `onEndReached={(e) => this.handleLoadMore(e)}`

Comment: You can see https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html. It's not necessary. This will give an error.

Comment: I'm telling you, you have to invoke the method. You're referencing a named method but you're never calling it.

Comment: I called in your ways. And as an expected result app crashed...